# How to generate a checksum for an java object

Tags: java, object, checksum

I'm looking for a solution to generate a checksum for any type of Java object, which remains the same for every execution of an application that produces the same object.

I tried it with [`Object.hashCode()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()), but the api says

> ....This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.

Comment: Can you add a link to the quotation?

Comment: @Roman: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29

Comment: `int checksum(Object o) { return 1;}` fills your requirements :-)

Comment: In more detail, I have to check if objects (marshalled xml request) between two application calls are the same or not.

Comment: @Alex: then why don't you compare the original XML for equality? That would probably be a much easier task than what you are attempting (even if you make it tolerate changes in whitespace or similar slight differences).

Comment: I agree with Joachim, both for simplicity and because using a hash value (checksum) is not error free, just error seldom, due to collisions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had similar problem (generating good hashcode for XML files) and I found out that the best solution is to use MD5 through [MessageDigest](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) or in case you need something faster: [Fast MD5](http://www.twmacinta.com/myjava/fast_md5.php). Please notice that even if `Object.hashCode` would be the same every time it is anyway too short (only 32 bits) to ensure high uniqueness. I think 64 bits is a minimum to compute good hash code. Please be aware that MD5 generates 128 bits long hash code, which should is even more that needed in this situation.

Of course to use `MessageDigest` you need serialize (in your case marshall) the object first.

Comment: thank you all for your answers. I calculate a MD5 from the marshalled request.

Answer (score 17):

```
public static String getChecksum(Serializable object) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(object);
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] thedigest = md.digest(baos.toByteArray());
        return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(thedigest);
    } finally {
        oos.close();
        baos.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Example

```
private BigInteger checksum(Object obj) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    if (obj == null) {
      return BigInteger.ZERO;   
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
    oos.writeObject(obj);
    oos.close();

    MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
    m.update(baos.toByteArray());

    return new BigInteger(1, m.digest());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you should look at [serialization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/). Serialization mechanism needs to solve similar problem, so you can look how it's implemented.

But if you describe the problem you're trying to solve you'll probably get more precise solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you control the source, you can implement hashCode() so it will be consistent from one execution to another.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to be able to do this for *all* Java objects?

In that case `hashCode()` doesn't work.

For some classes `hashCode()` has a stricter definition which guarantees equality across executions. For example [`String`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()) has a well-defined `hashCode` implementation. Similarly [`List`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and [`Set`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) have well-defined values, provided all objects that they contain *also* have well-defined values (note that the general [`Collection.hashCode()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#hashCode()) does *not* require the value to be well-defined).

For other classes you will have to use reflection recursively with some well-defined formula to build a checksum.

Answer (score 2):

Hashcode is OK. Either given class overrides `equals` and also, as contract demands, `hashcode`. By contract, if `equals` returns `true` hashcode must be the same.
Or class doesn't override `equals`. In this case different executions of your application cannot produce *same* object, so there is no problem.
The only problem is that some classes (even from Java API) break contract for `equals`.

Answer (score 2):

The Apache commons lang library provides a `HashCodeBuilder` class which helps building a hash code that fills your requirements from the class properties.

Example:

```
   public int checksum() {
     // you pick a hard-coded, randomly chosen, non-zero, odd number
     // ideally different for each class
     return new HashCodeBuilder(17, 37).
       append(property1).
       append(property2).
       append(property3).
       toHashCode();
   }
```

See [Commons Lang API](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you're f you're using Eclipse IDE then it has actions (under Source menu) to generate hashcode and equals functions. It allows you to choose the attributes of the class you want in the hashcode. This is similar to using the HashCodeBuilder approach that has already been suggested.

Alternatively you could stream the object to a byte array and generate an MD5 of that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Object -> String (For example, GSON - you will not have to write serialization not to list all fields of your class)
2. String.hashCode() -> int (Instead of Object.hashCode()! This realization of hashCode() depends on content of String, not on address in memory --- you can use it across different app launches, different threads, etc.)

(or 2. String -> md5)

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 * Calculate checksum of a File using MD5 algorithm
 */
public static String checkSumApacheCommons(Object obj){
    String checksum = DigestUtils.md5Hex(String.valueOf(obj));
    return checksum;
}
```