# Detect object changes for java serialization

Tags: java, serialization

I use java serialization to save my java objects into files. I would like to implement a new system where I only save the object if any changes have been made to it. Is there any java built in option to detect if an object changed during the execution of the program?

Or the only way to detect this is by using a flag that will change if any of the setters of the object is called?

Thanks

Comment: Correct, there is no built-in "dirty" flag for objects.   If you know your accesses are always through bean patterns, then you can accomplish maintaining that flag there.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644847/how-to-generate-a-checksum-for-an-java-object)

Comment: Another option is to use something like AspectJ to instrument bytecode when you load it and set a "dirty" flag whenever a field is changed.   This will work even if the access is not always from a bean pattern method.

Comment: @aldito2 - Hashcodes / checksums do not solve this problem.  If the checksum matches, you don't know if the object has been changed or not - as the mutation could map the object into a state which hash-collides with the original state.  You've got to check the whole object against the whole saved object, after that.

Comment: You have phrased your two questions as 1 (paradoxical) question: (a) No, there is nothing built-in (b) The method that you describe is not the only way to detect if the object has changed

Comment: @BadZen : AspectJ does not involve bytecode manipulation at runtime, it uses InvocationHandler

Comment: Huh, I thought it could do either/or.   What is "Load Time Weaving", then?   (I'm pretty sure that's what it is...  been awhile but I'm fairly certain I've done this)

Comment: Yeah, take a look at: https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ltw.html

Comment: @BadZen though a checksum/hashcode is not full-proof it is a way of optimizing the comparison, first compare the checksums and if they are the same then do a full comparison to ensure you dont have a collision on the checksum

Comment: There is nothing optimal about serializing every object that doesn't change (because its hash matches) - that is exactly the cost OP is trying to avoid when he was motivated to ask this question.